# How to get clean URL for pagination links in Symfony

Tags: symfony, pagination

All the Symfony URL's I'm using are nice clear SEO friendly type things... sites/new, sites/edit/1, etc

I have just installed the [knp pagination bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) to get pagination for my tables.

But the links being generated are like this: app_dev.php/sites?page=2

How can I get it to use the normal style of link, so page 2 would be like this: app_dev.php/sites/2

Any thoughts appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change routing definition for your action. Something like this:

```
/**
 * sitesAction
 *
 * @Route("/sites/{page}", requirements={"page" = "\d+"}, defaults={"page" = 1})
 */
public function sitesAction($page = 1)
{
    (...)
    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        $page/*page number*/,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('max_per_page', 10)/*limit per page*/
    );

    return array('pagination' => $pagination);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that exact same thing using the routing.yml file? I haven't used annotations for anything else and I'd like to keep it consistent.

Comment: Ah, just to update... I figured it out. Just needed too add /{page} to the pattern and `page: 1` to the defaults. Thanks!